# HTTP GET request with boost c++ - oauth2 access token

Tags: c++, http, boost, token, oauth-2.0

I need to connect from a c ++ application to a rest server, my problem is when sending the token access provided by the server.

I have tried in several ways but I can not find the correct syntax.

The rest server uses oauth2 for authentication and the token type is bearer.

In oauth1 I found this syntax:

```
std::ostream request_stream(&request_);
request_stream << "GET " << path << " HTTP/1.0\r\n";
request_stream << "Host: " << server << "\r\n";
request_stream << "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
request_stream << "Authorization: OAuth oauth_version=\"1.0\", "
<< oauth_signature_method=\"PLAINTEXT\", "
<<"oauth_consumer_key=\"<key>\", "
<<"oauth_signature=\"<secret>&\"\r\n";
request_stream << "Accept: */*\r\n";
request_stream << "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";
```

But for oauth2 I can not find the correct syntax.

Of all the attempts I have made I will highlight 2:

1.

```
std::ostream request_stream(&request_);
request_stream << "GET " << path << " HTTP/1.0\r\n";
request_stream << "Host: " << server << "\r\n";
request_stream << "Authorization: Bearer accesstoken\r\n";
request_stream << "Accept: */*\r\n";
request_stream << "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";
```

Error returned: "Exception: unspecified file(1): unterminated string"

2.

```
std::ostream request_stream(&request_);
request_stream << "GET " << path << " HTTP/1.0\r\n";
request_stream << "Host: " << server << "\r\n";
request_stream << "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
request_stream << "Authorization: OAuth oauth_version=\"2.0\", "
<<"oauth_token_type=\"Bearer\", "
<<"oauth_access_token=\"accesstoken\"\r\n";
request_stream << "Accept: */*\r\n";
request_stream << "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";
```

Error returned: "Response returned with status code 401"

Additionally, try without "\ r \ n" at the end of the line in both cases, but it doesn't work.

```
request_stream << "Authorization: Bearer accesstoken";

request_stream << "Authorization: OAuth oauth_version=\"2.0\", "
<<"oauth_token_type=\"Bearer\", "
<<"oauth_access_token=\"accesstoken\"";
```

I need the correct text string of the request "Authorization" to send the access token to the server:

```
request_stream << "Authorization: ??????? \r\n";
```

Does anyone know the correct syntax for sending the access token?

Thanks!!

**Edited - Nov 18**

Forget to mention that the rest server is made with symfony2 and fosrestbundle. Apparently fosrestbundle requires knowing it well to properly configure the service because otherwise it can give problems.

Now I'm testing rest with symfony3 and firebase-jwt. I guess I will not have problems because I can configure almost everything, without having to go so far in an outside bundle.

I have not tried with symfony3 and fosrestbundle, but it seems that fosrestbundle requires knowing it well to configure it correctly.

When I say that more advanced knowledge about this bundle is required, it is because it works me very well from other applications that I did, for example an android application; But from a c ++ application gives me problems.

I hope this information is useful for someone

**Edited Nov 21**

I tried with symfony3 and firebase-jwt and it keeps giving me the same errors.

I was wrong with fosrestbundle, in fact both servers (fosrestbundle and symfony3-jwt) do the authentication and correctly send the data that the client requests.

The problem is on the client side:

```
void Restclient::handle_read_content(const boost::system::error_code& err)
{
    if (!err)
    {
        std::ostringstream ss;
        ss << &response_;
        std::string s = ss.str();
        boost::property_tree::ptree pt2;
        stringstream is (s);
        boost::property_tree::read_json (is, pt2);

        boost::asio::async_read(socket_, response_, boost::asio::transfer_at_least(1), boost::bind(&Restclient::handle_read_content, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }
    else if (err != boost::asio::error::eof)
    {
        std::cout << "Error: " << err << "\n";
    }
}
```

After performing several tests, I verified that exactly in this line is where the error occurs:

```
boost::property_tree::read_json (is, pt2);
```

The json arrives well: (for example)

```
{ "Data1": "c ++", "data2": "java", "data3": "python", "data4": "php", "data5": "c #"}
```

I'm not going to put the actual json because it's a pretty long string, but it's just to give you an idea.

And at the moment of reading and converting to json, this appears:

```
{ "Data1": "c ++", "data2": "java", "data3": "python", "dat
Exception: <unspecified file> (1): unterminated string
```

The code I exposed here is based on examples of boost c ++ async_client, but it gives me that problem.

If someone has solved this problem, I would appreciate your help.

**Edit - Nov 27 [SOLVED]**

```
std::ostream request_stream(&request_);
request_stream << "GET " << path << " HTTP/1.0\r\n";
request_stream << "Host: " << server << "\r\n";
request_stream << "Authorization: Bearer accesstoken\r\n";
request_stream << "Accept: */*\r\n";
request_stream << "Content-Length: 0\r\n\r\n";

void Restclient::handle_read_content(const boost::system::error_code& err)
{
    if (!err)
    {
        boost::system::error_code error;
        string result = "";
        //Read the answer to the end
        while (boost::asio::read(socket_, response_, boost::asio::transfer_at_least(1), error))
        {
            std::ostringstream ss;
            ss << &response_;
            std::string output = ss.str();
            result = result + output;
        }

        //If the answer has already arrived and there is nothing left to read
        if (error == boost::asio::error::eof)
        {
            stringstream is (result);
            boost::property_tree::ptree pt2;
            boost::property_tree::read_json (is, pt2);
        }
        boost::asio::async_read(socket_, response_, boost::asio::transfer_at_least(1), boost::bind(&Restclient::handle_read_content, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }
    else if (err != boost::asio::error::eof)
    {
        std::cout << "Error: " << err << "\n";
    }
}
```

JSON is complete and ptree is generated correctly

Comment: An easy way to debug such things would be to try it with a library which provides easy APIs to work with OAuth2, for eg: python. If you get that working, its just too easy to figure out what that library is sending in headers using any tracing tool

Answer (score 0):

You have some `HTTP` formatting issues.

None of your requests are sending the size of the message body (in your case zero) and since you are sending `HTTP 1.0` requests, there is no need to send `Connection: close`, the server should close the connection after it has sent it's response. If you don't want that behaviour then change `HTTP/1.0` to `HTTP/1.1`.

Try replacing the last line of attempt 2:

```
request_stream << "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";
```

with:

```
request_stream << "Content-Length: 0\r\n\r\n";
```

You should receive a `200` (OK) or a `401` (Unauthorized) response.

FYI the syntax is defined in the HTTP specification, [RFC7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230), specifically [RFC7235](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235) for authentication.